# Derivative Identity: $ (dy/dx)^{-1}$

Tags: derivatives

Knowing that:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$$

And applying the exponent (-1) to both sides of the equation, may I say that:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}^{(-1)}=\frac{dx}{dy},$$

or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the mean of $^{-1}$? Here $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is an operator, not a number

Comment: A negative exponent.
E.g: 

$$\frac{5}{7}^{(-1)}=\frac{7}{5}$$

Comment: Moreover, the relation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$ holds only if the function $y$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a number, the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}^{-1}$ means $\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, and the equation $\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}} = \frac{dx}{dy}$ would be valid as long as $\frac{dy}{dx} \neq 0$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have in mind. So, this relation is only correct when the expression $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a number, in other worlds when it has been aplied over a function, not as a operator. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @MaximilianoSilva What would it mean to take a negative exponent of an operator?